# Ascensor plugin div between section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using ascensor Plugin for my website.
I have something like this

```
 <section>Section 1</section>
 <section>Section 2</section>
```

What I am trying to do is to put a div between the sections, but ascensor takes the height and width of the screen and stretches the section based on the screen which causes the div to not appear.
So what I did was to create:

```
 <section>Section 1</section>
 <section class="slicer" style="height:400px !important;">SLICER</section>
 <section>Section 2</section>
```

It worked but now I have space between the section and slicer. Any ideas on how to get rid of that space??

Comment: It seems like you're working against the tool rather than with it.

Comment: yeah i know but what to do(((